# sizeof error in a struct

Tags: c, struct

I keep getting  an error that says error:

```
invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct customer'
```

I don't know how to fix the problem. Can anyone suggest ways for me to alleviate this problem?

```
typedef struct
{
  int acc_number;
  char first_name[30];
  char last_name[30];
  char address [50];``
  int contact_info;
  float acc_bal;
} customer ;

struct employee
{
  int emp_id;
  char first_name[30];
  char last_name[30];
  char address [50];
  char job_title [30];
  int contact_info;
};

int main()
{

  FILE *myPtr;
  customer customer = { 0.0 };

  if ( ( myPtr = fopen( "credit.dat", "r+" ) ) == NULL )
    printf( "File could not be opened.\n" );
  else {
    printf( "Enter account number"
          " ( 1 to 100, 0 to end input )\n? " );
    scanf( "%d", &customer.acc_number);

    while ( customer.acc_number != 0 ) {
      printf( "Enter lastname, firstname, balance\n? " );
      fscanf( stdin, "%s%s%f", customer.last_name,
              customer.first_name, &customer.acc_bal );
      fseek( myPtr, ( customer.acc_number - 1 ) *
             sizeof (struct   customer ), SEEK_SET );
      fwrite( &customer, sizeof ( struct customer ), 1,
             myPtr );
      printf( "Enter account number\n? " );
      scanf( "%d", &customer.acc_number );

    }

    fclose(myPtr);
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

You do not have a `struct customer`.

You have a struct with no tag with an alias of `costumer`.

Try

```
typedef struct costumer { /* ... */ } costumer;
//             <--tag->               <-alias->
//      <--type name-->
//      <-------------type---------->
```

Or, maybe even better, leave `typedef` out of your code.

Comment: Additionally `fseek(.... )` is incorrectly written, without `\\` we can't write `*` expression in multiple lines

Comment: I am not a C programmer, but the few code I have seen uses `typedef`s, why would you *leave `typedef` out of your code*?

Comment: thaks very much this helped alot

Comment: To me, `typedef` only adds another name for something which already has a very good name. I don't need two names to refer to one thing. *The only time I use `typedef` is for function pointers.*

Comment: @pmg: But without lookup crossing to the user-defined-types automagically all uses of the `struct` are more verbose. The advantage is that the new name is in a different place than the old one, and is easier to find by lookup.

Comment: I think some people prefer not typing `struct` when dealing with structures, and they use an alias to hide that part of the type name. I prefer to type `struct` and know with a single glance that I am working with a structure.

Comment: I too use `struct` when wanting to emphasize the `struct` nature of the object.  Other times, the nature of the object, be it `union`, `struct`, `int`, pointer, etc., I want to be hidden via `typedef` (might not even know it when roughing out code) to be more OOP-like.  It prevents an application module from counting on `struct`-ness.  In all cases, do not like `struct` tags, type names, nor object names to overlap.

Answer (score 2):

As @pmg well points out why the below fails: code does not have a `struct customer`.

```
fwrite( &customer, sizeof ( struct customer ), 1, myPtr );
```

---

The declaration of the variable `customer`, though legal uses "customer" in 2 different ways.

```
customer customer = { 0.0 };
```

Suggest using the `sizeof` with the variable name and not the type name.  Also use distinguishing type and variable names.

```
customer current_customer = { 0.0 };
fwrite( &current_customer, sizeof current_customer, 1, myPtr );
```

Even if one prefers to not use`typedef` and use `struct` when declaring variables, still recommend using `sizeof` with the variable name and not the type.

```
struct customer {
  int acc_number;
  ...
  float acc_bal;
};

struct customer current_customer = { 0.0 };
fwrite( &current_customer, sizeof current_customer, 1, myPtr );
```

Comment: +1 good point about using the object as operand to the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @pmg  Thanks.  Over the years I've found `sizeof object` rather than `sizeof type` less error-prone and less work to maintain`.